# Read PDF in selenium: The constructor PDFParser(BufferedInputStream) is undefined

Tags: selenium, pdf, selenium-webdriver, testng, pdfbox

I am getting error

> The constructor PDFParser(BufferedInputStream) is undefined

I am trying to read PDF contents using Selenium.

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.axmag.com/download/pdfurl-guide.pdf");
URL TestURL = new URL("http://www.axmag.com/download/pdfurl-guide.pdf");
BufferedInputStream TestFile = new BufferedInputStream(TestURL.openStream());
PDFParser TestPDF = new PDFParser(TestFile);
TestPDF.parse();
String TestText = new PDFTextStripper().getText(TestPDF.getPDDocument());
System.out.println(TestText);
Assert.assertTrue(TestText.contains("Open the setting.xml, you can see it is like this"));
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same Propblem you have faced. The problem is due to using (Apache PDFBox 2.0.0 API) jar Files.
Remove them from build path and use (Apache PDFBox 1.8.11 API) as PDFParser class in 2.0 doesn't have PDFParser(BufferedInputStream args) Constructor. But 1.8 has PDFParser(InputStream args) Constructor. So it will Definately Solve your Problem.

I will also share my code. if you need Help you can take from that.

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(getLatestFile);
        PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(is);
        parser.parse();
        String output=new PDFTextStripper().getText(parser.getPDDocument());
        System.out.println(output);
        parser.getPDDocument().close();
```

Comment: Might work, you're using an outdated method of opening files. (that is found on several SEO websites)

Comment: The comment below solves the problem without having to revert to an older version of the library. I recommend using that solution.

Answer (score 4):

The best code for PDFBox 2.0.2 (also works in 1.8.*) would be this - you only need to call `PDDocument.load()` to open a PDF file:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.axmag.com/download/pdfurl-guide.pdf");
URL url = new URL("http://www.axmag.com/download/pdfurl-guide.pdf");
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(bis);
String text = new PDFTextStripper().getText(doc);
doc.close();
bis.close();
System.out.println(text);
Assert.assertTrue(text.contains("Open the setting.xml, you can see it is like this"));
```

Comment: PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(bis); <-----This one line solved my problem with this page here: http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-extract-pdf-text-and-verify-using-selenium-webdriver-java

This should be the accepted answer, as the other requires you to revert to an older version of PDFBox, which is not a good idea for many reasons.

Comment: It's the person who asked the question who decides what the accepted answer is. Sometimes the accepted answer has less votes that another answer 